# adding the aws executable to your OS's PATH environment variable: needed every time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, aws-cli

I am following the install directions outlined in this article (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html#awscli-install-linux-path)to install the AWS CLI on a Raspberry Pi. 
(OS: PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)")

The steps are pretty straightforward though I am running into a problem with the section called "Adding the AWS CLI Executable to your Command Line Path"

Following the instructions I determined that I need to run the following two commands to complete this step:

```
$ export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
$ source ~/.profile
```

once I do this I can run `$ aws` and I see the following message as expected:

```
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: too few arguments
```

All good so far.  If I close my terminal and then re-open a new terminal and I try to run an command starting with `aws` I get the following:

```
bash: aws: command not found
```

I have found that if I re-run the following...

```
$ export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
$ source ~/.profile
```

... then it works again... until I close my terminal window.

So my question is:

Is this expected behavior, to have to re run these commands every time I want to work with the AWSCLI? Or should this step be a do-once-and-done. I admit I don't know very much about the nature of these commands, or what they are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for that link. It's helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour of export and source. You will find yourself doing the same thing for other programs as well, not just aws-cli.

A better way would be to edit the `~/.profile` file and add `export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` at the end of file.

Every time you open a new shell session, the `.profile` file is loaded, and the export will be run.

Comment: if I dont have this file is it ok to create it? Will it be used?